# Adding data to marquee tag at run time

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, marquee

I am trying to add data at run time to marquee tag in css using java script but unfortunately nothing is working in the sense there is no display at all. My logic looks to be correct.

Below is the code:

```
<label > <marquee id="marque" direction="up"><p> starting point </p> </marquee></label>

<script type="text/javascript">

var count;
var getdata=${message};  //data from servlet passing to jsp
var storedata = new Array(); //array to split string and store in array
var displaydata;

storedata=getdata.split("-");
for (count=0;count<storedata.length;count++){

    //displaydata=displaydata+storedata[i]+"\n";
    document.getElementById("marque").innerHTML="<p>storedata[i]</p> ";
}
</script>
```

I am expecting that as loop starts one by one data should be added to marquee.

Comment: Just for reference, [Marquee is an obsolete tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) and shouldn't be used.

Comment: @JoshuaM Thanks for reply.. in this case what is the work around what need to be used?

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for reply... Actually content inside loop is not getting displayed on the screen one which is out side loop is visible.

Comment: But seriously, if I put your code in a fiddle, it does work. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/2rrdkzfc/ So something else must be going on that you're not showing. Ehm, did you want to display `storedata[count]`?

Comment: Thanks for reply... yeah it should be count... sorry for that actually I am totally disturbed its not working for sometime now so playing with it but unfortunately when changed to count also it is not working... Can you please help me

Comment: It depends on what you want. Does it look like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/2rrdkzfc/2/) has the desired result?

Comment: @MrLister sir actually its working when I run only JSP but when I run servlet it is not working

Comment: What I have noticed is data is getting passed from servlet to jsp but when I run nothing is displayed again if I hardcode the values that servlet pass to JSP its working

Comment: @Siva Then the data is either no coming in at all, or it's in the wrong format. Do you get errors in the console when the JavaScript is run?

Comment: No Sir.. Data is coming in JSP for sure because when I use `${message}` outside javascript I can see the full string but when I use the same Javascript there is no display.  If I am not wrong do we need to call the JavaScript function explicitly to execute? I guess that part is causing the issue to my knowledge.. May be javascript is not getting called

Comment: I am new this JS stuff sir.. If I am troubling you I am sorry

Comment: I have observed when I run JSP along everthing is workinig fine and when I run servlet then JS is not getting invoked but if I don't use JS then again everything is working fine but required functionality is not able to achieve